# How to get the id of the clicked row on a clickable table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table where every row has an id, so when any row is clicked, I would like to know which row was clicked, so I can apply different actions to it.

Any suggestions on how to do it using jQuery or any other means?

Comment: What do you mean by **dynamic**? And **what** have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the site guidelines on asking good questions to learn how to frame your questions in a way that are helpful to you, useful to future searchers, and possible for the members of the site to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that your tables are dynamic, so you should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here!

See this prototype:

```
$(document.body).on("click","tr",function(){
   console.log($(this)) //this will be refereed to current row clicked 
   // other stuff here
});
```

here in place of `$(document.body)` you can have closest parent element / container.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `id` of a `tr`:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
   alert( $(this).attr('id') );  
})
```

Comment: Why wrap the `this` reference in JQuery when you can just do `this.id`?

Comment: Well, maybe he wants to get another attribute than id in the future for example?

Comment: @web_student It's better practice to avoid creating jQuery objects needlessly. If it turns out OP wants another attribute later, they can still grab it from the DOM element directly via `this.getAttribute()`. There are plenty of good reasons to create jQuery elements, but this isn't one of them.